# Is there a way to detect redirect vs refresh in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have routes that fires in this order:

```
router.post("/data",(req,res)=>{
   //Get request.body.ID
   //Query database for data usinf the ID
   const query = queryString.stringify({
            "orderID": orderID[0].orderID,
            "data" :data
        })
      res.redirect('/details?' + query)
})


router.get("/details", (req, res) => {
     renderDetailsObject = {
      orderID: req.query.orderID,
      data : req.query.data
     }
      res.render("orderDetails", renderDetailsObject)
}
```

If the get `details` route follows the post data route, I will get the latest data after my database query but if someone refreshes the page `details` it will not give me the latest data:

For example if the details route in the url bar looks like :

```
/details/orderID=23&data=dsadsa
```

Refreshing the page will just use the same data instead of going through my post route first to get the latest data.

Therefore, I wanted to know if there is way in Nodejs using express I can tell the difference between a refresh vs a page redirect so that I can bascailly requery the database if it is refresh.

Also, please let me know if there is any other way to solve this issue

Comment: I don't understand. If `GET` should get the latest data from database, why use `POST` at all?

Comment: Your POST should not be a post as it's not doing anything that a POST would do in a REST design - it looks like it should be a GET.  And, you shouldn't be redirecting either.  If you want to share that code, just put the code in a common function you can call from multiple routes.

Comment: I can use req.body in the get route